# How to do set nx option using RedisTemplate?

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I'm trying to use Spring Data Redis APIs, and want to execute a set with nx option. However, I don't find a relevant method in RedisTemplate. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The method name is `setIfAbsent`

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/BoundValueOperations.html#setIfAbsent-V-

Comment: what if I want to add an expire time at the same time? setIfAbsent doesn't provide an argument for expire time.

Comment: setIfAbsent support set expire since 2.1 version